# Inserting data in two columns on same row simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in a mysql database with only two columns and I want to insert data in both columns on the same row simultaneously using php. I have tried the following `php script` but it inserts data in the one row then the other as follows:

```
1-NULL
NULL-4
```

I want both 1 and 4 to be on the same row. Here's my `php script`:

```
<?php
    $first_value = 1;
    $second_value = 2;

    $qry = "INSERT INTO my_table (first_value) VALUES ('$first_value')";
    $qry .= "INSERT INTO my_table (second_value) VALUES ('$second_value')"; 

if($conn->multi_query($qry) === TRUE){
echo "success";
}
else {
echo "Error: " . $qry  . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

It inserts successfully. But I want the insert to be on the same row. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `INSERT INTO my_table (first_column, second_column) VALUES ('1', '2')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a proper insert

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO my_table (first_value, second_value) 
  VALUES ('$first_value', '$second_value')";
```

Comment: how foolish of me :)